# Detect when the user has muted AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I am playing a live stream using AVPlayer and AVPlayerItem.
Is there a way to know if the user has muted/unmuted the video while playing it

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `isMuted` value of the AVPlayer.

Documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1387544-ismuted

Comment: Yes I know the property of AVPlayer but I wanted  a way to get notified whenever user mutes/unmutes the player without keep checking this property.

Comment: are you using any standard player interfaces or a custom one?

Comment: Standard player interfaces

Comment: Ok, AVPlayer should supports KVO, I would try with them.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cocoa_design_patterns/using_key-value_observing_in_swift

Comment: I already did try that. But there is not property of AVPlayer to observe for volume change.

Comment: @shoan have you get any solutions yet?

Comment: @webmastx I found no solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `KVO` and `Combine` to observe changes to `isMuted` property:

```
let player: AVPlayer
private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

//...

player
    .publisher(for: \.isMuted)
    .sink { isMuted in
        // here you can handle the fact the the user has muted or unmuted the player  
     }
     .store(in: &cancellables)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement KVo to detect mute/unmute changes.

**Note:** in swift, although the property is `isMuted`, but you still should use ObjectiveC properties in KVo, so listen for `muted` key and you are set.